# square always exponentiation method

Tags: python, exponentiation

besides the square-and-multiply method, there is this method square-and-multiply-always, and i am trying to implement it in python. My problem is that during searching i found a pseudocode for it, [here](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00633545/file/square_always.pdf) and i implemented it in python but it does not yield the correct results in comparison to pow function.
The pseudo code can be found in the link above or in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMTA3.png).

My implementation is

```
def square_and_multiply_always(base, exp, mod):
    R0=1
    R1 = base
    c = '{0:b}'.format(exp)
    i=len(c)
    t=0
    while i>=0:
        if(t==0):
            Rt=R0
        elif(t==1):
            Rt=R1
        else:
             print("t != 0 or 1")
        R0=(R0*Rt)%mod
        a=int(c[i-1])
        t=(t^a)
        i=i-1+t
    return R0
```

Comment: As a side note, I can suggest you use better variables names. It's very hard to follow what you're doing on each step.

Comment: Isn't `R` supposed to be an array?

Comment: You use `i` differently from the paper (algorithm 2.4, isn't it?) When `i` equals 0, you will then do `a=int(c[-1])`.

Comment: @GalAbra variable names are as in the paper except "a" which in the paper is denoted as "d" and ArndtJonasson i dont think i use i differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i managed to find my mistakes so here is a proper code for future searches that end up here

```
def square_and_multiply_always(base, exp, mod):
    R0=1
    R1 = base
    c = '{0:b}'.format(exp)
    i=len(c)-1
    t=0
    c=c[::-1]
    while(i>=0):
        if(t==0):
            Rt=R0
        elif(t==1):
            Rt=R1
        else:
            print("t != 0 or 1")
        R0=(R0*Rt)%mod
        d=int(c[i])
        t=(t^d)
        i=i-1+t
    return R0
```

Comment: With some help.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson indeed, thank you all for your help :D